# Where does the extra empty <option> come from?

Tags: php, html, html-select

```
<?php
$salaries = array(1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,9000,12000,18000,30000);
$str = '';
foreach($salaries as $salary)
{
    $str .= "<option value=\"$salary\">$salary+</option>";
}

function populateSalary()
{
    $salaries = array(1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,9000,12000,18000,30000);
    $str = '';
    foreach($salaries as $salary)
    {
        $str .= "<option value=\"$salary\">$salary+</option>";
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
<select id="salaryExpect" name="salaryExpect">
    <option value="-1">--<option>
    <?php echo populateSalary(); ?>
</select>
```

See?There is no such empty option as `<option>  </option>` in the code,but strange enough there is in the output.

Can have a look here:
http://maishudi.com/test3.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line

```
<option value="-1">--<option>
```

You're not closing the tag, you're opening another, it should read

```
<option value="-1">--</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<option value="-1">--<option>
```

is the error , change it to

```
<option value="-1">--</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line `<option value="-1">--<option>`, your close tag isn't actually closing. It should read:

```
<option value="-1">--</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please look carefully at the first "option" in the output, you forgot to close the tag :)